# jquery ajax function not do anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

all Ajax not working in my project, 
my structure project is
`http://localhost/aaa/beranda.php?h=Add-Pengeluaran`

The jquery code is as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#tampil').load("tampil.php");
            $("#Submit").click(function() {
            var data = $('#form').serialize();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "insert.php",
                data: data,
                cache: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#tampil').load("tampil.php");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

please help me

Comment: Please clarify your question, what is the error log or the expected behavior that is not working?
Why do you say ur ajax is not working? U can check it in chrome's console's sources tab
Also i'd recomend you to add some console.log && echo in your js/php files so you can check if it's working propertly.

Comment: Please share your code in JSFiddle

Comment: You cannot *just* share a link to your localhost without an IP. `/localhost` in my environment is not *your* localhost. Please [edit] and add the necessary to create a [mcve]. Read also [ask].

Comment: How do you import jQuery? Remember that some minified versions do not include ajax, does the console log tell you something?